# Why do I get either NoReverseMatch or FieldError

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project, and want to create a report on a film. (That it doesn´t exist) At the moment I only get error when I try to go to either film// or film//report. Can anybody help me?

**When I try film//:** NoReverseMatch; Reverse for 'film-report' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['film/(?P[0-9]+)/report$']

**And film//report gives:** FieldError; Unknown field(s) (reported) specified for Report

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(default="")
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Reporter")
    # receiver = models.ForeignKey(
    #     User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Receiver"
    # )
    reports = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return f"{self.reporter.username} reports {self.reports.title}"
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.films_view, name="board-home"),
    path("film/add", FilmAddView.as_view(), name="film-add"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/", FilmDetailView.as_view(), name="film-detail"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/report", FilmReport.as_view(), name="film-report")
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class FilmReport(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ["title", "reported"]
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.title

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This should be the page where I can click on "Report", and then be redirected to a report page.

**film_detail.html**

```
{% extends "board/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle film-img" src="/media/{{object.poster}}">
  <!-- Mulighet for å ha en "add review"-knapp på siden der hvor filmene vises. -->
  <a href=" {% url 'film-add' %}" class="waves-effect waves-light green btn"><i class="material-icons right">rate_review</i>add review</a>
  <a href=" {% url 'film-report' %}" class="waves-effect waves-light red darken-4"><i class="material-icons right">report</i>report</a>
  <!-- <a onclick="myFunction()" class="waves-effect waves-light red darken-4 btn"><i class="material-icons right">report</i>report</a>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var txt;
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to report this film?")) {
        $("#inline2").fadeIn(300);
        $(".overlay-fixed").fadeIn(300);
        $(".fancybox-opened").fadeIn(300);
        return false;
      } else {}
    }
    </script> -->
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="film-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="film-plot">{{ object.plot }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class FilmReport you can just take the fileds from your model Report.
The field "reported" does not exist. You should take "reporter" or "reports".

You can just try the urls you have specified, either film nor film/report are valid urls. You need to have at least one Film object in your database to get access to the url 
film/1/report.